# We're Graduating out of Beta Status!

Tags: discussion, status-planned, moderation

We're coming up on the 7th anniversary of our fledgling site being in beta status. As of this post, we've been around for 2553 days. Phew!

It is our pleasure to report from the moderator team that we have been scheduled to be fully graduated on **December 16**. Thank you to the many helpful members of the community who have helped keep this site healthy and informative all these years. It's certainly been a long journey.

What does this all mean?

- You keep all your reputation points from while in beta.
- Full moderator elections will happen probably in 2022. A lot of sites are going to be coming out of beta, so we're not sure about the exact scheduling yet.
- Site design customization won't be part of graduation for now. But that doesn't mean we can't start breaking out some human capital to find the artists within us willing to come up with cool logos or banners.

Again, thank you all who have contributed positively to our site for all these years, however new you might be. We appreciate the dedication and support.

Comment: This is amazing news! There were some long years when the beta seemed like it would be endless and it's great to know that the maturity and the vitality of the site will now be recognised.

Comment: This is great news! Incidentally, [what happens to privileges earned during the beta phase?](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2162/what-happens-to-privileges-earned-during-the-beta-phase-when-a-site-graduates)

Comment: I have replied in your thread, but leave this here for others' benefit: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331710/345389

Comment: I believe there is this saying, "a fair day's wage for a fair amount of days' work" - 2583 days to be exact. At last. Great news.