# What happens to privileges earned during the Beta phase when a site graduates?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, reputation

It was recently announced that our site is [graduating from Beta status](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/were-graduating-out-of-beta-status?cb=1) in December.

What happens to privileges earned while in beta? For example, I'm not there yet on this particular site, but 500 rep grants close vote privileges on sites in beta, but on "graduated" sites you need 3000. Will everyone that has at least 500 rep (but less than 3000) simply lose their close vote privileges?

Another example: I have 12k rep on another Beta site, but I have privileges that would normally require 25k rep on a graduated site (e.g. the ability to immediately vote to delete closed questions with a score of -3 and the ability to view site analytics). If that site were to graduate, would I simply lose those privileges?

Answer (score 5):

The last time a lot of sites were updated out of beta, the voting privileges were not changed right away, but on a case by case basis. See this query: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331710/345389